# How to write code in typescript to make private member in javascript after tsc?

Tags: typescript

When I am using private keyword in typescript, tsc generates javascript code with public members. So private members of class in typescript are public members in javascript. Please look at [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09private%20helper()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(%22helper%22)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B)

How to write code in typescript to receive private members in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

In javascript you can create private members using [revealing module pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)

```
var MyClass = function() {

    var privateMember = function () {}


    return {
        publicMember: function () {}
    }
}
```

If you use typescript class, it is not possible, because it's generate prototype, which does not have private methods.